# Messages in iCloud Option Unavailable on Mac

Tags: mac, icloud, messages

I'm running macOS 10.13.5 and am trying to enable Messages in iCloud on Mac. I went to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208532 and completed the "Before you begin", "Turn on Messages on iCloud" and "On your iPhone" sections without issue. It's the "On Your Mac" section where I'm having trouble:

1. Open Messages.
2. In the menu bar, choose Messages > Preferences.
3. Click Accounts.

However, this is not available:

4. Select the checkbox next to Enable Messages in iCloud.

[image]
[image]

Any idea how I can enable Messages in iCloud on my Mac?

Comment: It could be a feature that's enabled by default in the background when signed in with an Apple ID.

Comment: Were you able to follow the "Before you begin" section and activate it on your other devices?  Are all devices using the same Apple ID?

Comment: @fsb Yes. Enabled Messages in iCloud on iPhone using the same Apple ID as the Mac.